# iOS app with Azure Mobile App service in low bandwidth areas

Tags: ios, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to design an enterprise mobile app that is to be used worldwide. There are some countries where in the network bandwidth is very low. The app would require to download and upload packages ranging from 5mb - 30mb. What are your suggestions for design patterns and mechanisms to ensure optimum performance when working with Azure Mobile App service. The primary use case here is synchronisation of the above packages over a low bandwidth network.

Answer (score 1):

1) Split your data down into the smallest units possible.  It's rare that a data record is actually 5MB-30MB - generally, rows are a few Kb at most - this will translate into less data being transferred on a per-sync basis.

2) Set up offline sync in the language of your choice - Azure Mobile Apps supports [iOS (Obj-C, Swift)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-offline-data/), [Android (Java)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-offline-data/), [Windows](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data/) and [Xamarin (C#.NET)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-ios-get-started-offline-data/) for offline sync.  Cordova support is on its way.

3) Consider adopting configuration options such as "only sync on wifi" or "push to sync" - these will help alleviate the bandwidth concerns on cellular.

Comment: on #1 - In the as-is solution, I have sqlite DB being downloaded and uploaded for a near to 100% offline capability. A whole bunch of data is downloaded for the field force to perform their activity throughout the day or at times for multiple days. In the target scenario, if I go with Azure mobile app service as the MBaaS..how can I ensure that such amount of data is downloaded and yet maintain an optimum performance on a low bandwidth network..

Comment: Once you have offline sync, there is a SQLite database (eventually) for storing that data.  When you update the server store, you set an updatedAt field + compute a new version.  When the client connects, it gets all records that have been updated since a specific date.  As a result, only the minimal amount of data is transferred.

Comment: In addition... you can specify a VIEW of the data - minimize the data that the mobile client sees while keeping the full data set on the server.   This is then optimized for the mobile client and low bandwidth scenarios.